# CSS From Parent Component Not Applying to Child Component Angular 9

Tags: css, angular, routes

I have a component nested within a component with a bunch of HTML. In the parent component, I am trying to have the CSS written there apply to the nested component.

Example:

```
/* this is within the parent css */
button{
    color: red;
}
```

But then in the child the component's button is not red.

I am linking the components like so:

```
<!-- this is within the HTML of the parent -->
<div>
    <nested-component></nested-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend `:host ::ng-deep` to achieve this.

```
:host ::ng-deep button {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: If you don't need the css applied to anything in the parent component, you can also move that css to a child-component stylesheet, and forego the `:host ::ng-deep` prefixes (potentially with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` if you need it).